# Elegant way of integrating for loop with a flag in Python

Tags: python, loops, python-click

I am using click to create a command line tool that performs some data preprocessing. Until now, I have basically survived using click.option() as flag with some if statements in my code so that I can choose the options I want. However, I am struggling to find an elegant way to solve my next issue. Since I believe the general code structure does not depend on my purposes I will try to be as general as possible without getting into details of what goes into the main code.

I have a list of elements `my_list` that I want to loop over and apply some very long code after each iteration. However, I want this to be dependent on a flag (via click, as I said). The general structure would be like this:

```
@click.option('--myflag', is_flag=True)
#just used click.option to point out that I use click but it is just a boolean
if myflag: 
    for i in my_list: 
        print('Function that depends on i')
        print('Here goes the rest of the code')
else:
    print('Function independent on i') 
    print('Here goes the rest of the code')
```

My issue is that I wouldn't like to copy paste twice the rest of the code in the above structure (it is a long code and hard to integrate into a function). Is there a way to do that? That is, is there a way to tell python: "If `myflag==True`, run the full code while looping into `mylist`. Otherwise, just go to the full code. All of that without having to duplicate the code.

EDIT: I believe it might actually be useful to go a bit more specific.

What I have is :

```
mylist=['washington','la','houston']

if myflag: 
    for i in my_list: 
        train,test = full_data[full_data.city!=i],full_data[full_data.city==i]
        print('CODE:Clean,tokenize,train,performance')
else:
    def train_test_split2(df, frac=0.2):
        # get random sample
        test = df.sample(frac=frac, axis=0,random_state=123)
        # get everything but the test sample
        train = df.drop(index=test.index)
        return train, test
    train, test = train_test_split2(full_data[['tidy_tweet', 'classify']])
    print('CODE: Clean,tokenize,train,performance')
```

`full_data`is a pandas data frame that contains text and classification. Whenever I set `my_flag=True`, I pretend the code to train some models an test performance when leaving some city as the test data. Hence the loop gives me an overview on how does my model perform on different cities (some sort of GroupKfold loop).

Under the second option, `my_flag=False`, there is a random test-train split and the training is only performed once.

It is the CODE part that I don't want to duplicate.

I hope this helps the previous intuition.

Comment: You could consider a filtering generator expression `(do_thing(x) for x in my_list if my_flag)`, although I'm unsure if this would have a performance penalty (since from memory the condition is checked every iteration)

Comment: But with this I would still need to integrate all the code into ```do_thing(x)```and then call it again for the case ```my_flag=False```, right?

Comment: In that case you could have a `(do_thing(x) if my_flag else do_both_things(x) for x in my_list)`?

Comment: I don't get what you consider duplicate code here. If you mean that the ``print('CODE: ...`` part is a stand-in for some actual code... doesn't that depend on `i` in the first but not second case, so not being comparable?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes, that part is exactly where the code would enter. It is a code that does not depend on i directly but on the distribution of train-test. What I want in the first case is to run it once per each combination of train-test (splitting by cities), and on the second case just run it once using the random split. Hope this clears up my intentions a bit.

Comment: The proper way to repeat code is to put it into a function. What is the reason the code is "hard to integrate into a function"?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to avoid that firstly because the code is a bit messy (that's why I wondered whether there is a more elegant solution). The rest of the code is built within another function (typical cli() function), so it has a lot of options and arguments and also calls other functions from different modules. It could be certainly done but it will take me a lot of time to adapt it... If it was something shorter I wouldn't even hesitate to do that or even copy paste it twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "hard to integrate into a function"? If a function is an option, just use the following code.

```
def rest_of_the_code(i):
    ...    
if myflag:
    for i in my_list: 
        print('Function that depends on i')
        rest_of_the_code(i)
else:
    print('Function independent on i') 
    rest_of_the_code(0)
```

Otherwise you could do something like this:

```
if not myflag:
    my_list = [0] # if you even need to initialize it, not sure where my_list comes from
for i in my_list:     
    print('Function that may depend on i')
    print('Here goes the rest of the code')
```

EDIT to answer regarding your clarification: You could use a list which is iterated.

```
mylist=['washington','la','houston']
list_of_dataframes = []
if myflag: 
    for i in my_list: 
        train,test = full_data[full_data.city!=i],full_data[full_data.city==i]
        list_of_dataframes.append( (train, test) )
else:
    train, test = train_test_split2(full_data[['tidy_tweet', 'classify']])
    list_of_dataframes.append( (train, test) )
for train, test in list_of_dataframes:
    print('CODE: Clean,tokenize,train,performance')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! What I mean by hard to integrate is that the rest of the code depends itself on a lot of @click options and it is also defined within another function (the typical ```cli()```function). It is a bit of a nightmare to fully put it into something that resembles ```rest_of_the_code()```. Wrt ```my_list```, this is a pre-specified list of cities that I want to loop over. I believe your second option will just loop over the first city but in this case I want to do something different. I will update the main post now with some more information sorry about that.

Comment: You are welcome, hopefully this is more helpful!

Comment: Thanks again. I believe here the final code will only run for the last iteration (last city), won't it? In the first case I would like it to run once per city to check the performance when using different cities as train-test. As the call to the code goes outside the loop, it will do it only for the case where houston is the test dataset.

Comment: The last it will run for all cities combined as you called the train_test_split2 function with full_data and not any filter (like full_data[full_data .city == "Houston"]) on the city. Here:
    train, test = train_test_split2(full_data[['tidy_tweet', 'classify']])

Comment: What I mean is that for the case where ```myflag==True```, the part where the main code goes ```'CODE: Clean,tokenize,train,performance'```, will do it only for the case where Houston is the test data but I want this code to be run once per every combination of cities in test-train. That is: put Washington in the test--run the code, now put la--run the code, Houston--run the code.

Comment: In the `myflag==True` case it iterated over all the cities in `mylist` and adds all combinations of datasets to the `list_of_dataframes`.
The main code `CODE: Clean,tokenize,train,performance` in the for-loop is executed for each dataset in `list_of_dataframes`. This takes into account each city that you appended in the  `myflag==True` case and not just the last.

Comment: Oh, you are totally right! Sorry for the confusion! This is indeed doing what I want. Thanks!